# mono develop:c# multiple projects

Tags: linux, mono, project

in VS there is an option for the Solution to create multiple projects inside, but it seems in mono this option is missing and I can debug just one project in a time. Is there a way like in VS for Windows to have multiple projects in solution and switch between them?

Regards,

Comment: Are you talking about MonoDevelop?

Comment: Hi, yes exactly. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: are you talking about multiple solutions instead of multiple projects? because a solution can already hold multiple projects, both in VS and MonoDevelop